# How use live server open currently edit html?

Tags: html

i use live server in Visual Studio Code

but click bottom and right "Go Live"

[image: other html file context]

show someone file context.

How use live server open currently edit html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your terminal is not in the folder in which the file is located or there are multiple HTML files in your folder then live server will not be able to locate or display your file

### Solutions

1. In the menu you see after clicking `go live` select the HTML file you want to view
2. Name the HTML file you want to view as `index.html`. when the server sees this file. It knows that this is the HTML file to be displayed as the landing page.

Comment: If change terminal path is work ? but how ?

Comment: i change name to index.html still not work

Comment: did you try solution no 1 @Shawn-

Comment: terminal path is worng so i can't see target html

Comment: solution 1 works because VSCode will only look in the current folder and will only give extensions like live server access to the current folder for security reasons

Comment: @Shawn- correct your terminal path by executing this command in your terminal `cd <path to your folder in which the target.html is present>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223832/discussion-between-akionsight-and-shawn).

Comment: terminal path i change. but executing live server has hard loading....i give up but sill thank your 
patient teaching

Comment: welcome @Shawn-